# Multiple table JOIN's returning duplicate results, facebook-like activity wall

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates

Quick sum up: I have a social website where users can follow/post/vote etc. I am adding a new facebook-like activity wall feature to each users profiles.

I have worked on this bit for a few days now and can't seem to get it to work properly. What I want is, well, exactly like the facebook wall as I mentioned...When a visitor visits a user's profile, that user's activity will display, whether they recently "voted" on a post, commented, or posted something of their own, I would like it to display on their profile and of course, have the most recent entries on top.

The problems I am having right now are: it's displaying some things twice and it's not sorting them by the most recent.

I am working with 3 tables here (I only posted the columns that I am using):

```
Table structure for table votes_posts
Field   Type    Null    Default
indexer int(11) No  
post_id int(11) No  
vote    int(11) No  
user_name   varchar(250)    No  
date    varchar(255)    No  

Table structure for table posts
Field   Type    Null    Default
id  int(11) No  
name    varchar(30) No  
content text    No  
datetimerss varchar(255)    No  
category    int(11) No  

Table structure for table comments
Field   Type    Null    Default
id  int(12) No  
post_id int(12) No  
name    varchar(30) No  
content text    No  
type    varchar(30) No  
datetimerss varchar(255)    No
```

$users is just $_GET['user']
The timeAgo() function, simply displays the very popular "posted xx ago" date time.

```
<ul class="streamActivity">
<?php
$checkActivity = "SELECT votes_posts.post_id, votes_posts.user_name, votes_posts.vote, votes_posts.date, 
                        posts.id, posts.content, posts.name, posts.datetimerss, categories.category, 
                        comments.post_id AS comm_postid, comments.content AS comm_content, comments.name AS comm_name, comments.datetimerss AS comm_date, comments.type 
                        FROM `votes_posts` 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN `posts` ON votes_posts.post_id = posts.id 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` ON posts.id = comments.post_id 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` ON posts.category = categories.cat_id  
                        WHERE (votes_posts.post_id = posts.id AND user_name = '$user')
                        OR (comments.post_id = posts.id AND comments.name = '$user')
                        OR (posts.name = '$user') ORDER BY votes_posts.date, posts.datetimerss, comments.datetimerss ASC";
$checkActivityResult = mysql_query($checkActivity);

if (mysql_num_rows($checkActivityResult) > 0) {
    while ($sessionAct = mysql_fetch_array($checkActivityResult)) {
        $category = strtolower($sessionAct['category']);
        $dateVote = timeAgo($sessionAct['date']);
        $datePost = timeAgo($sessionAct['datetimerss']);
        $dateComm = timeAgo($sessionAct['comm_date']);

        $namePost = $sessionAct['name'];
        $nameComm = $sessionAct['comm_name'];
        $nameVote = $sessionAct['user_name'];

        $idVote = $sessionAct['post_id'];
        $idPost = $sessionAct['id'];
        $idComm = $sessionAct['comm_postid'];

        $contentPost = $sessionAct['content'];
        $contentComm = $sessionAct['comm_content'];
        $typeComm = $sessionAct['type'];

        if ($namePost == $user) {
            $classList = 'storyPost';
            $classIcon = 'iconMuttr';

            $name = $namePost;
            $content = $contentPost .' ... read more';
            $datetime = $datePost;
        }

        elseif ($nameComm == $user && $typeComm == "Comment") {
            $classList = 'actionPost';
            $classIcon = 'iconComment';

            $name = $nameComm;
            $content = 'Commented "'. $contentComm .'"';
            $datetime = $dateComm;
        } elseif ($nameComm == $user && $typeComm == "Advice") {
            $classList = 'actionPost';
            $classIcon = 'iconAdvice';

            $name = $nameComm;
            $content = 'gave Advice "'. $contentComm .'"';
            $datetime = $dateComm;
        }

        elseif ($nameVote == $user) {
            if ($sessionAct['vote'] == "1") {
                $classList = 'actionPost';
                $classIcon = 'iconLaughed';

                $name = $nameVote;
                $content = 'Laughed at "'. $contentPost .'"';
                $datetime = $dateVote;
            } elseif ($sessionAct['vote'] == "2") {
                $classList = 'actionPost';
                $classIcon = 'iconLoved';

                $name = $nameVote;
                $content = 'Showed Love on "'. $contentPost .'"';
                $datetime = $dateVote;
            } elseif ($sessionAct['vote'] == "3") {
                $classList = 'actionPost';
                $classIcon = 'iconIdiot';

                $name = $nameVote;
                $content = 'called '. $namePost .' an Idiot for "'. $contentPost .'"';
                $datetime = $dateVote;
            }
        }
?>
    <li class="row-activity <?php echo $classList; ?>">
        <a href="" class="avatar"><img src="/images/avatars/default_male.jpg" /></a>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="userName">
                <a href=""><?php echo $name; ?></a>
            </div>
            <span class="msgBody"><?php echo $content; ?></span>
            <div class="imgTimeStream">
                <span class="img <?php echo $classIcon; ?>"></span>
                <span class="source"><?php echo $datetime; ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>This user has no recent activity.</p>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

I am by no means an expert programmer...everything I know I have pretty much taught myself over the past year or two, so I can only imagine how ugly this truly is lol. I am learning each and everyday though, and I hope to continue :)

Also, within each type of activity, there will be slightly different CSS classes on some things.
Example:
if the result row is a post then the css class of the list item would be "post"
if the result row is a vote then the css class of the list item would be "vote"
etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE: Well multiple Queries seemed to work fine...no more duplicates. I even have it only displaying the last couple of months of activity (for now anyway). Now I need to figure out how to mix the results, so the most recent one's (whether it's a vote or post, etc.) be at the top.

P.S. I probably should mention that A LOT of data will be passing through this (think of a facebook wall+twitter feeds lol)

Comment: Welcome to SO! My suggestion would be for you to break this up into distinct parts and query separately. A bit difficult to pinpoint the data without actually looking at the resultset you get

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) I was thinking about that as well...Although I am not sure how I would mix them in all together and order them by the most recent. Right now, the resultset I have up looks like this: post1, post1, showed love, called idiot, post2, post2

Comment: think of the things you need to display a single item on the "wall" - eg: date, title & body. Now write separate SQL queries that return those columns for each type of object.

Comment: Once you've done that, chuck a `union all` between each query, and an appropriate `order by` at the bottom.

Comment: Can't seem to get UNION's to work (I've never used them before, so that could be the problem) I am going to try what @JohnP suggested and use 3 different queries.

Comment: Well multiple Queries seemed to work fine...no more duplicates. I even have it only displaying the last couple of months of activity (for now anyway). Now I need to figure out how to mix the results, so the most recent one's (whether it's a vote or post, etc.) be at the top.

Comment: i ended up just creating a new DB table 'activities' and having things post there, so all I need to do is pull up activities :) so far it's working like a charm, and way easier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should turn your query into a union of 3 statements (votes, posts, comments) that return the same set of columns. What's happening in your query is that multiple votes, posts or comments are multiplying out the rows generated by the query.

As an aside, you should convert to using parametrized SQL if possible, to eliminate potential SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: THank you for the suggestion! However, using UNION means each table needs to have the same columns right? (if not, by all means let me know) This would not be possible.

Comment: you can rename columns in your query: `select p.post_body as body from post p`

Comment: ohh, awesome!! Was not aware that I could rename them to be identical :D This alone will help tremendously I believe, thanks! Now if I did this, how would I differentiate the result outputs? Ex: how would i display a vote.date versus post.date?

Comment: I just wanted to add that this type of data lends itself to caching especially well. I highly recommend caching the result set as long as you can. If you don't need the feed to be accurate to the second, consider caching it. Even a very short life cache will help reduce the number of times you have to run this query.

Comment: To differentiate the different result outputs, add another column that just returns a constant - such as 1 for votes, 2 for comments, etc.  Then you can check that column to tell the different types of result apart.